# Using json_encode on php $_GET array results in string rather than array of strings

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to use the php GET method to create an array of keywords from a keywordBox field on another page.

Here is an example of the keywords appended to the page URL:

/searchResults.php?keywordBox=computing+finance

This looks okay to me but when I convert to a JSON object it seems the keywords become a single string ("computing finance") rather than array of strings (["computing", "finance"])

```
var keywords = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['keywordBox']) ?>;
alert(keywords[0]);  // output "c"
```

I thought this would output the first word in the array "computing" instead it outputs the first character "c"  so I'm a little confused and new to these languages. Any explanation greatly appreciated.

Comment: json_encode returns a string and string's 0 index is its first character.

Comment: @Taplar That's not correct. You only run `JSON.parse()` on strings that contain JSON, but the output here is going to be a literal string: "computing finance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keywordBox` can be an array, just change your query string with:

```
?keywordBox[]=computing&keywordBox[]=finance
```

Otherwise you can keep it as a string, and `explode` it.

```
var keywords = <?php echo json_encode(explode(' ', $_GET['keywordBox'])) ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will decide whether using the array notation in the URL as you suggested or using explode will suit my needs better

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to what you're encoding.

This only encodes one GET parameter, not the `$_GET` superglobal array:

```
var keywords = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['keywordBox']) ?>;
```

With your given URL and the parameter `keywordBox=computing+finance`, `$_GET['keywordBox']` will contain a single string, `"computing finance"`, not an array. If you want the parameter to contain an array, you need to use array notation, as in `keywordBox[]=computing&keywordBox[]=finance`.

Comment: Ah i see, thanks for your response, i thought i was encoding an array but obviously not.